# How can I make a Macbook Pro to recognise a connected mouse as a mouse?

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, trackpad

Apologies for the vague title. Please tell me if I've done something wrong with this post so I can rectify it.

I have a Logitech MX Anywhere 2 mouse that works fine with my computer, apart from one thing. Even with the "Ignore built-in trackpad when mouse or wireless mouse is present" checkbox checked in Accessibility, my trackpad still accepts input even while my mouse is connected. I am able to move the cursor with the trackpad and the mouse at the same time, which I assume means that the computer is somehow not accepting the wireless mouse as a mouse. It is connected by Bluetooth and the options in System Preferences for mice still affect it. By the way, my trackpad turns off when I have any other mice connected.

Does anyone know how to get the computer to recognise the mouse for this option, or to otherwise spoof a connected mouse so that the trackpad will be deactivated?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried resetting the NVRAM?

Source:  [How can I disable the trackpad when my mouse is plugged in on Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21540/how-can-i-disable-the-trackpad-when-my-mouse-is-plugged-in-on-lion)

How to rest NVRAM:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063